# logrorate.d generating files that have endlessly appended dates and doesn’t see to compress files

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, logrotate, syslogd

I tried to configure my `logrotate.d` as below, it generates files with funny names (ex: `0220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425-20220426` appended to it), I want to check is it working as expected since it is my first experience? As I am not sure why it creates files with zero sizes?

My expectation was:

- rotate 7 times
- per day
- missing okay
- notifempty
- compress the files
- max size of the file shouldn't be more than 50MB
- max age of files shouldn't be more than 100 days

My config file in `/etc/logrotate.d/myconfig` is as below. Did I configure my configuration properly and the naming is correctly generated?

```
/data/meter-logs/messages_*[!.gz]
{
  rotate 7
  daily
  missingok
  notifempty
  compress
  maxsize 50M
  maxage 100
  postrotate
        syslog-ng-ctl reload > /dev/null
  endscript
}
```

My files are in this `/data/meter-logs/` directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3.5K Apr 26 19:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 21 03:34 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 22 03:42 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 23 03:17 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421-20220422
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 24 03:46 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 25 03:15 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 26 03:45 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   83M Apr 20 03:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425-20220426
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 23 03:17 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220421
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 25 03:15 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220421-20220423
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12K Apr 21 03:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220421-20220423-20220425
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 24 03:46 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220422
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 26 03:45 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220422-20220424
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5.3K Apr 22 03:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220422-20220424-20220426
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 25 03:15 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220423
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5.1K Apr 23 02:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220423-20220425
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 26 03:45 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220424
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5.5K Apr 24 03:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220424-20220426
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5.1K Apr 25 02:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220425
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5.5K Apr 26 03:28 messages_electricity_meter-dev-20220426
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20 03:34 messages_electricity_meter-test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 21 03:34 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 22 03:42 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 23 03:17 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421-20220422
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 24 03:46 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 25 03:15 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 26 03:45 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1.4G Apr  3 05:03 messages_electricity_meter-test-20220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425-20220426
```

Comment: Please edit your question: “…it generates files with funny names…” What does this mean? Can you provide some examples of these “funny” names so we can all see what you are seeing?

Comment: @Giacomo1968: sure I mean it is adding date at the end of the file name like 0220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425-20220426

Comment: Please take note that previously I was configured to add date to the name of log but after that I removed it but it still behaves the same way even after restarting the service.

Comment: So there is a file name that is `0220420-20220421-20220422-20220423-20220424-20220425-20220426`?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes it is

Comment: Looking at what you are doing, I believe you are missing `create` which would create a new log file. If you somehow needed to create files with specific ownership and permissions, the `create` line could look like this: `create 0644 root some-group`; of course change the `0644`, `root` and `some-group` to match your needs.